# Does Stimulus Targets Have to be Nested Under Stimulus Controller in the DOM?

Tags: stimulusjs

All the examples/tutorials I have seen for building out controllers and targets for stimulus have the targets nested under a parent element that has been declared as using a data controller.

For example (from the [handbook](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/managing-state):

```
<div data-controller="slideshow">
  <button data-action="slideshow#previous"> ← </button>
  <button data-action="slideshow#next"> → </button>

  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any recommendation or hard rule that the targets must be nested under the controller? Can the following be used:

```
<div data-controller="slideshow">
  <button data-action="slideshow#previous"> ← </button>
  <button data-action="slideshow#next"> → </button>
</div>

<div id="someOtherDiv">
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
  <div data-slideshow-target="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is the closest I've found to be what you are asking https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/outlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In order for targets to relate to the controller, they need to be within that controller's scope. That means that you must have an element with `data-controller="my-controller"` as the parent element for any HTML elements with `data-my-controller-target="myControllerTarget"`. You *can* have a controller and a target on the parent element, though, and you can also have several controllers assigned to a single parent element. For the example you provided, I would recommend moving the controller declaration up to a common parent element.